# How stop lxml logging errors in python

Tags: python, lxml

I can not stop the errors in python. No matter what I do, it always shows this error:

```
validity error : ID some_id already defined
```

I'm using Python 3.4.3 and Lxml 3.4.4

Comment: Have you tried using a try-catch clause?

Comment: If the data don't contain duplicates, then there might be a bug in your code. Try to provide a reasonable code snippet which reproduces this error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved, a error when call function cleaner from lxml

```
doc = clean.Cleaner(
            scripts=True,
            javascript=True,
            comments=True,
            embedded=False,
            meta=True,
            page_structure=False,
            links=True,
            style=True,
            forms=True,
            safe_attrs_only=False,
            remove_unknown_tags=False
         ).clean_html(doc)
```

Solution:

```
c = clean.Cleaner(
            scripts=True,
            javascript=True,
            comments=True,
            embedded=False,
            meta=True,
            page_structure=False,
            links=True,
            style=True,
            forms=True,
            safe_attrs_only=False,
            remove_unknown_tags=False
        )
        doc = c.clean_html(doc)
```